# Error creating JButtons in an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

I am writting a program that will have a 9x9 button which will have each button go from 1 to 81 starting in the upper left to going right

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MS extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static JFrame bframe;
    static JPanel p;

    public MS() {
        p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9,9));  
        private static JButton[][] jgo = new JButton[9][9];
        int count = 1;
        for(int row=0; row < 9; row++)
            for(int col=0; col < col; col++) {
                jgo[row][col] = new JButton("%d",count);
                p.add(jgo[row][col]);
                count++;
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        bframe=new MS();    //CREATE me and 
        bframe.add(p);      //add the JPanel

                bframe.setSize(810,810);
        bframe.setLocation(0,0);                //where my upper left hand corner goes
        bframe.setVisible(true);                //I start out invisible
        bframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //need this for the window manager
    }
}
```

My error occurs in my constructor it has something to do how I make the buttons and set the value.

Comment: And "my error" is what? And ew, what's with the statics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go the list of constructors for JButton class

```
JButton()
      Creates a button with no set text or icon.
JButton(Action a)
      Creates a button where properties are taken from the Action supplied.
JButton(Icon icon)
      Creates a button with an icon.
JButton(String text)
      Creates a button with text.
JButton(String text, Icon icon)
      Creates a button with initial text and an icon.
```

There is not any one like the one you are using.

```
JButton("%d",count); // JButton(String,int); or JButton(format,int);
```

Instead you can use

```
JButton(""+count)://JButton(String text)
```

Answer (score 3):

`JButton` doesn't have any constructor that in the form of `JButton(String, int)` for formatting purposes, You probably want to do:

```
new JButton(Integer.toString(count))
```

instead of

```
new JButton("%d",count)
```

---

*Side Notes:*

You can't use the `private` keyword in a constructor:

```
 private static JButton[][] jgo = new JButton[9][9];
    ^
```

This line will exit immediately:

```
for (int col = 0; col < col; col++) {
```

as `col < col` will evaluate as `true` and the inner loop won't be executed.

This statement can only be valid in the class block.

Static variables are generally considered poor design. The variables `bframe` and `p` could be used be used in local scope.